# QGIS raster statistics from information panel different to Raster Layer Statistics algorithm

Tags: qgis, raster, statistics

I am wondering why the raster layer statistics presented in the Information panel are different to those calculated using the Raster Layer Statistics Algorithm?

I note the line STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES, which suggests that only approximate stats are calculated, but I would like to know how they are calculated.
[image: Information Panel]

[image: Algorithm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overviews on your raster dataset, the approximate statistics might be based on an overview rather than the full dataset. The GDAL documentation has a very brief description on approximate statistics here: [gdalinfo / approx_stats](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html#cmdoption-gdalinfo-approx_stats)